# Rails start up is very slow

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a PC with 2 processors of 2GHz and 4go of ram. I use Ubuntu 12.04 and it's the same think with windows and Ubuntu 11.10. I use RVM with ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf and rails 3.2.3. When I load my rails application, it take a few time and I think it's not normal.

This is some example :

```
time rails new speed_test
...
real    0m7.240s
user    0m4.484s
sys     0m0.184s

time rails g scaffold Articles title:string description:text
...
real    0m4.910s
user    0m4.052s
sys     0m0.348s

time rake db:migrate
...
real    0m4.172s
user    0m3.716s
sys     0m0.244s

time rake
...
real    0m15.981s
user    0m14.045s
sys     0m1.048s
```

This is some short commands but, with some hundred of tests, it's very long, even with spork. My processor is used to 20/30% during a test.

UPDATE :
With tests of this projet : https://github.com/railsfrance/railsfrance.org it take about 6 minutes.
Do you have a solution?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: We all know rails could be faster, and a lot of developers works on speeding this up, instead of asking this question again, try to trace it and propose solutions for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that's expected. Loading all of Rails and your app takes time. For example, in my app, loading the development environment takes around 7 seconds of real time, so any command that works with the app *must* take at least that amount of time. Your load time appears to be even *faster*, either because your app is smaller or your computer is faster.

Additional processing power is probably less likely to make a huge difference than an SSD.

Also, note that comparing things like `rails new` (which potentially hits the internet as it does `bundle install`), `rake` (which runs your tests), or `rake db:migrate` (which may or may not do things) is mostly meaningless.

You can usually improve your startup time by reducing the number of gems that are required.

Comment: I compared my time for an application with some other users. My time was about 6 minutes and for others it take 40sec/1minutes. The application is : https://github.com/railsfrance/railsfrance.org and I tested command "rake test".

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you talk about anything taking six minutes, everything in your question takes less than 16s.

Comment: Yes for simple commands, but for many tests it take a lot of time.

Comment: @Dougui Again, your question makes no reference to running tests. Even if it did, it would be meaningless without comparisons to running the exact same test suite on different machines. I've worked on apps where running all the tests takes around an hour, that doesn't mean that there's a problem with the machine—it's just how long they take to run.

Comment: Ok, so you than time for the railsfrance project seems normal? Why some other users go 6x faster and my processor is used simply at 30%? I updated my post.